# What tool(s) are appropriate for cutting a door opening in shipping container?

Tags: powertools, metal-cutting

I'm thinking about buying a shipping container to use it for storage/bike shed/workshop. I can get one from a retailer with an extra door, but this would be rather expensive. So now I'm investigating ways to do this myself. The first question is how to get the hole into the container wall.

What are possible tools with their pros and cons and approximate cost that are able to cut through the wall of a shipping container, for long (~2m) straight cuts?

Answer (score 3):

There are many tools for cutting steel.  In addition to what you have suggested you could use:

1. A "sawzall" type reciprocating saw.
2. An oxy-acetylene torch.
3. A plasma cutter.
4. A body grinder with a cutting disc.

If you are good at following a marked line freehand then you should be able to just cut away and get the result you want.  If your cuts tend to drift, you might put together some sort of guide to keep the cuts straight.

(Since you asked...)
If I had to choose one, for example if this was my project, I'd probably opt for the plasma cutter route.  Plasma cutters cut through sheet steel like a hot knife through butter and leave a very clean edge.  The biggest con with them is that it can be tricky to keep a straight line.  But a straightedge of some sort will fix that issue easily.

Comment: Could you extend this answer with some comments for each tool? I've already figured that it's in principle possible with a torch or a saw or a grinder but now looking which tool to get.

Comment: "In addition to what you have suggested" where were these suggestions? Did I miss some comments that got deleted? #confused

Comment: that comment might refer to the other answer

Comment: @Jasper you asked for a list of tools, not instructions on how to setup and use each one.

Comment: "possible tools with their pros and cons and approximate cost"

Comment: Approximate cost? If you do your own research, you will become a better person. Have folks become so lazy that they will type out questions with more words than a internet search with two to four words!? "Sawzall cost near me"

Comment: “Pros & cons” for a professional or a first time user?

Comment: @Gunner This is a help forum. Having all the answers in one place helps other people in the future, rather than everyone having to do the same thing over and over again.  So yes, I think having an answer with costs, tradeoffs, etc is helpful.

Comment: “First time user" seems clear enough to me.  @SolarMike

Comment: @SteveSether is that how this place works? Thanks. Price for something near me could be $50, and someone else could be $150 for the cms tool. This is why we don't discuss prices here.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica and "first time user" is where in the original question?

Comment: @SolarMike a professional would not ask.... "The first question is how to get the hole into the container wall."

Comment: @Gunner well I would start with a pilot hole, but a louisiana spanner will make its own.

Comment: @Gunner Odd.  I find prices on tools to be largely similar, especially in the age of Amazon.

Comment: @SolarMike pretty much all over the entire question.  Which is on a DIY forum, note. Put another way, why would a pro ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the fastest, cleanest way to cut it is with a saw.
There are circular saws made for cutting metal such as the  Milwaukee 6370-20.  It can make plunge cuts to start the cut.  You could attach a straight scrap of 2x4 or something to guide straight cuts.

[image: Milwaukee 6370-20]

For a shipping container this might be overkill, it's a real beast and can cut much heavier things.  You  can get metal cutting blades for regular circular saws that will cut metal roofing materials.  However the shipping container is going to be a lot heavier than metal roofing so I'd say use the metal cutting circular saw to be safe.

Comment: It won't get the corners without cutting past, so you will need a reciprocating saw also.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - you do have a point.  In thin material, you'd only have to cut past by about the thickness of the metal.  That might be no problem, covered up with the door framing.

Comment: The "overcut" at the corners would be no problem with the ~3mm(?) steel.

Comment: Seen some cuts by gas axe that would easily match the finish needed to weld to a future door frame...

Comment: I'm a fan of the plasma cutter if you've got access to a good one (maybe a friend? ) use a guide for straight lines, and zip zip clean cuts.  I've never been able to get a straight line with a sawzall,or 'demosaw' as I call em.